# Option Value is not the same as the one displayed

Tags: arrays, reactjs

i have a select input and i'm mapping over an array of strings to display the options inside it so i what i want to do is when to open the select input and pick one option i take that value and put it in a variable but the problem is the value that i get is not the same as displayed didn't know why

this is the component code :

```
<Select
    value="none"
    style={{ width: '60%', marginLeft: '15%', marginTop: '10%' }}>
    <MenuItem value="None">
        <em>None</em>
    </MenuItem>
    {
        values.modules.map((module, index) => {
            return (
                <div key={index}>
                    <MenuItem 
                         onClick={this.handleSelectChange}
                         value={module}>
                      {module} 
                    </MenuItem>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </div>
            )
        })
    }
</Select>
```

and this is the handleSelectChange function :

```
 handleSelectChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        result: this.props.values.modules[event.target.value]
       }, function () {
        console.log("selection" + this.state.result);
      })
    }
```

so the value that i get is an int it's like the index of that item in that array despite the {module} outside value it works fine it shows me the value of that item didn't know what's wrong

Comment: Hi AOUADI please try my solution below and let me know if that helps :)

Comment: you can use react-select, hope it will be very helpful.. https://react-select.com/home